# Sending E-mail notifications for two different dates.

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-ucm

I have a requirement form one of the department from my company, they want to have two dates in their `content profile`, one is `expiring date` and other is `follow up date`. Their demand is they want to have notification from `expiring date` `one month before` and for the `follow up date` they want to have notification after every `seven days`. I know how to handle the notification for `expiring date`, that part is done. The issue is not don't know how to achieve notification fucntionality with `follow up date`.

I have developed a custom component for this, in which I have wrote code for the mail sending for `follow up date`. But the issue is for I am not being able to fetch the author's email address and for temporary basis I have hard coded the email address for that.

I would like to know from you guys, if I am on the correct path, If I am then how should I fetch the Author's Email address.

PS: If required I will post my java component's code here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using the OOTB Notification of Expiration component?

Comment: You can ask for clarification on the comment. Don't post these queries as answer.